# A partir de uma lista, devolver os números pares em python

Tags: python

Estou tentando retornar somente os números pares de uma lista1=[4,3,2,5,7,6]

para o retorno em uma lista2=[2,4,6]

Tentei o método recursivo com for mas retorna o erro: TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for %: 'list' and 'int'

```
lista1 = [4,3,2,5,7,6]
lista2 = []

for lista2 in lista1:
    if lista1 % 2 == 0:
        print(lista2)
```

Comment: Que tal `lista2 = [ el for el in lista1 if el % 2 == 0 ]` ?

Comment: A propósito, sua função não tem nada de recursiva. E você fez uma bela bagunça com as variáveis

Comment: Obrigado Jefferson. A propósito, quando vc diz 'bagunça com as variáveis' , o que quer dizer? Agradeço imensamente ajuda, estou iniciando os estudos em Python e qualquer crítica construtiva é bem vinda.

Comment: Você declara `lista2` como sendo uma lista vazia. Então usa como variável de iteração no laço `for`, porém compara uma operação com a variável `lista1` dentro do laço. Essa a confusão.

Comment: Você está confundindo conceitos bem básicos necessários para estruturar um programa. Responder a questão de forma que você entendesse equivaleria a uma "aula 0" - acho que  a recomendação que fica é você procurar algum tutorial de Python para iniciantes em programação, e ler até que ensinem sobre "variáveis", "listas" e o comando "for".

Comment: Show pessoal, obrigado pelas dicas!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Além de estar de acordo com as confusões já expostas nos comentários anteriores, uma forma de solução seria:

```
lista1 = [4, 3, 2, 5, 7, 6]
lista2 = []
for valor in lista1:
    if valor % 2 == 0:
        lista2.append(valor)

print(lista2)
```

o "valor" no for é a variável temporária que salva os itens da lista1

```
for valor in lista1:
```

logo, no condicional se "valor" tem resto 0 na divisão, ele é adicionado à lista2 usando a função append()

```
if valor % 2 == 0:
        lista2.append(valor)
```

Comment: obrigado mmtz, ótima explicação.

Answer (score 0):

> para o retorno em uma lista2=[2,4,6]

Ou seja, em uma **lista de pares ordenados**, utilize [filter](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/functions.html#filter) para **filtrar os pares**, e [sorted](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/functions.html#sorted) para **ordená-la**.

```
lista1 = [4, 3, 2, 5, 7, 6]
lista2 = sorted(filter(lambda x: x % 2 == 0, lista1))
```

Comment: Show!! Vlw sbrubes. Excelente